# JAVA 8: исключение в stream

Tags: java, java-stream, java-8

Есть ли возможность обработать исключение в stream по-другому, без `try/catch` блока?

```
 return Streams.stream(iterator)
            .map(item -> {
                try {
                    return mapper.readValue(item.toJSON(), Customer.class);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Error occurred during convert JSON to Customer", e);
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: А зачем вы делаете `.collect` и снова `.stream`?

Comment: дейстительно, можно сразу `filter`, изменил

Comment: Ответ: Нет, нельзя.

Comment: Можно извлечь логику с try/catch в отдельный метод:
`.map(this::processItemWithPossibleException).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно обойтись и без перехвата исключения. Так как контроль проверяемых исключений осуществляет компилятор, а виртуальная машина не делает разницы между проверяемыми и непроверяемыми, можно в райнтайме сгенерировать обёртку, не содержащую выбрасываемых исключений в сигнатуре.

```
import java.lang.invoke.CallSite;
import java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@FunctionalInterface
interface ThrowingFunction<T, R, E extends Exception> {
    R apply(T t) throws E;
}

class Wrappers {
    public static <T, R> Function<T, R> uncheckedFunction(ThrowingFunction<T, R, Exception> function) {
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodType factoryType = MethodType.methodType(Function.class, ThrowingFunction.class);
        MethodType functionType = MethodType.methodType(Object.class, Object.class);
        try {
            MethodHandle method = lookup.findVirtual(ThrowingFunction.class, "apply", functionType);
            CallSite cs = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "apply", factoryType, functionType, method, functionType);
            return (Function<T, R>) cs.getTarget().invokeExact(function);
        }
        catch (Throwable exc) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(exc);
        }
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("{\"a\": 1}");
        //items.add("абракадабра");
        items.add("{\"b\": 2}");

        TypeReference<Map<String, Integer>> type = new TypeReference<>() {};
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        items.stream()
             .map(Wrappers.uncheckedFunction(i -> mapper.readValue(i, type)))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Но в отличии от моего предыдущего примера, если исключение всё-таки возникнет, оно остановит выполнение программы, если не будет перехвачено в месте работы со стримом или выше.

P.S. Объявление `TypeReference` стало компактнее благодаря более умному выводу типов в Java 11.

Answer (score 1):

Перехват исключения можно вынести в абстракцию, что позволит сократить и облагородить код использования в лямбдах методов, выбрасывающих исключения.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ThrowingFunction<T, R, E extends Exception> {
    R apply(T t) throws E;
}

class Wrappers {
    public static <T, R> Function<T, R> ioFunction(ThrowingFunction<T, R, IOException> function) {
        return v -> {
            try {
                return function.apply(v);
            }
            catch (IOException exc) {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("{\"a\": 1}");
        items.add("абракадабра");
        items.add("{\"b\": 2}");

        TypeReference<Map<String, Integer>> type = new TypeReference<Map<String, Integer>>() {};

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        items.stream()
             .map(Wrappers.ioFunction(i -> mapper.readValue(i, type)))
             .filter(Objects::nonNull)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```